# How to set present screensize in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have working with swing API for the first time to get the screen resolution for my win application.

How to set present screensize in Java Swing?

Comment: A Java developer rarely if ever, needs to get the screen size.  And that is even if creating a full screen frame or window.  Why do you think this app. needs the screen size?

Comment: *"How to set present screensize.."*  BTW - by 'set' DYM 'get'?  It seems most of the answers presumed 'get' but the questions states 'set' twice.

Answer (score 2):

The question depends.  Do you want the full screen size or the usable screen size (minus things like the taskbar and the dock)? Do you want the default screen or a specific screen?

## Full Screen Size, any device...

First you need to grab a reference to the current `GraphicsEnvironment`...

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
```

Then you can grab a list of the `GraphicsDevice`s available on the system...

```
GraphicsDevice lstGDs[] = ge.getScreenDevices();
```

Or if you just want the current/default screen, you can use...

```
GraphicsDevice device = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
```

Anyway, which ever you choose, next, you need to get the `GraphicsConfiguration` from the device...

```
GraphicsConfiguration cf = device.getDefaultConfiguration();
```

And finally, you can grab the screen bounds, this includes the position and size of the screen within the virtual desktop...

```
Rectangle bounds = cf.getBounds();
```

## Safe/viewable screen size...

This takes into consideration things like the task bar or dock or other UI elements the OS might have on the screen, which you shouldn't try and appear over/behind.  Not everybody has these at the bottom of the screen ;)

Start by grabbing your `GraphicsConfiguration` from your selected `GraphicsDevice`, from this, get the screen bounds...

```
GraphicsDevice device = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice(); // or what ever device you want...
GraphicsConfiguration cf = device.getDefaultConfiguration();
Rectangle bounds = cf.getBounds();
```

Next, get the screen insets...

```
Insets insets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(gc);
```

This represents the area taken up by the OS to display its extra stuff.  Now, reduce the screen bounds by the insets...

```
bounds.x += insets.left;
bounds.y += insets.top;
bounds.width -= (insets.left + insets.right);
bounds.height -= (insets.top + insets.bottom);
```

This represents the safe/viewable area you window can appear in without been blocked by this other elements...

## Let the Swing API do it for you...

Or you could just use [`JFrame#setExtendState`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState(int)) and pass it `JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH` which will take care of it all for you...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = dimension .getWidth();
double height = imension .getHeight();
```

For your JFrame use `setSize(Dimension  dimension)` to set size

Comment: This will not take into account things like the task bar or dock or other UI elements the OS might have occupying the desktop, which could result in portions of your UI been cut off.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
int height = screenSize.height;
int width = screenSize.width;
//set size to the JFrame
this.setSize(width,height);
```

Comment: How is that different from Vishvesh Phadnis answer of 11 minutes earlier?