# Java Fullscreen Image resizing?

Tags: java, image, swing, fullscreen

Hello I am kind of new to java. I am working on a game. when the game starts a loading screen appears and the  fades away that's it so far. My question is simple. Is there a way to change the image size to fit the size of the computer screen. I want it to fit all types of screen sizes and be a larger scale of the original image. Here is my Main class so far(there are other classes like player and title and play but they are irrelevant to the question:

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Comp extends Canvas implements Runnable, KeyListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
    public boolean run = true;
    public Image screen, img;    
    public static double dir = 5;
    public static int pixelSize = 1;    
    public static Dimension size = new Dimension(680, 500);
    public static Dimension pixel = new Dimension(size.width / pixelSize,
            size.height / pixelSize);    
    public static int mx;    
    public static manager m;
    public static int my;
    public static int fps;    
    public static boolean mr;    
    public static boolean ml;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();    
    public Thread t;    
    public boolean splashscreen = true;
    public int time = 0;
    public int timer = 140;    
    public int btime = 0;
    public int btimer = 1;     
    private int FPS = 5;
    private long targetTime = 1000 / FPS;

    public Comp() {
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);    
        addKeyListener(new listen());
        addMouseListener(new listen());
        addMouseMotionListener(new listen());
        addMouseWheelListener(new listen());    
        m = new manager();
        requestFocus();    
        // h = new InputHandler(this);
    }

    public void start() {
        run = true;    
        frame.add(this);    
        frame.pack();
        frame.requestFocus();    
        frame.setTitle("In The Maze");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);    
        frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("res/traps/beartrap1.png").getImage());    
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        run = false;    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Comp c = new Comp();    
        c.start();
    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(2);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);    
        if (!splashscreen) {    
            m.render(g);
        }           
        if(splashscreen){
            ImageIcon i62 = new ImageIcon("res/splashscreen.png");
            img = i62.getImage();
            g.drawImage(img,(int)0 ,(int)0,Comp.size.width+10,Comp.size.height + 10,null);            
            time++;
        }    
        g.dispose();    
        bs.show();
    }

    public void tick() {
        if(time >= timer){
            time = 0;
            splashscreen = false;
        }

        if(!splashscreen){
            m.tick();
        }
        Keys.update();
        Esentials.tick();    
    }

    public void run() {
        screen = createVolatileImage(pixel.width, pixel.height);                
        long start;
        long elapsed;
        long wait;          
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();          
        while (run) {
            start = System.nanoTime();
            fps++;
            if(System.currentTimeMillis()  - currentTime >= 1000){
            //  System.out.println("fps:" + fps);    
                currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                fps = 0;
            }
            tick();
            render();
            elapsed = System.nanoTime() -start;    
            wait = targetTime = elapsed / 1000000;              
            try {
                Thread.sleep(wait);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent i) {
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent i) {
        Keys.keySet(i.getKeyCode(), true);    
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent i) {
        Keys.keySet(i.getKeyCode(), false);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use **Toolkit.getScreenSize()**

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();
```

For resizing the image you can use simple **imgscalr** library

```
BufferedImage scaledImage = Scalr.resize(myImage, 100);
```

Comment: but then how could I resize the image

Comment: and how would I apply that to my image?

Comment: you need to setup it somewhere in method: resizing of your image can be everywhere. Maybe it can be in constructor when you work at first time with it, or maybe you need some init method. You should decide.

Comment: what doe scalr represent?

Comment: @user50369 about Scalr you can see the official javadoc here http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/downloads/software/imgscalr/javadoc/org/imgscalr/Scalr.html

Comment: Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize() is a unreliable measure of the screen size, as it does not take into consideration other UI elements the os might have on the screen, like the dock or task bar

Comment: @MadProgrammer There are no UI elements on the screen when you use the full screen...

Comment: ok b444gf I looked at this page do I need to download any librarys because Scalr does not import or work for me

Comment: do I need to create a class myself

Comment: yes you need to add library to classpath. you can use simply IDE, or mvn/gradle. as you wish

Comment: @GilbertoTorrezan As near as I can tell, the op isn't using full screen exclusive mode, even if they were, they should be using the size of the canvas itself

Answer (score 1):

Determining the screen size...

- [How to set present screensize in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27031807/how-to-set-present-screensize-in-java-swing/27031968#27031968)
- [Full-Screen Exclusive Mode API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/)

Scaling the image...

- [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928)
- [Quality of Image after resize very low -- Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752)
- [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)

I'd also discourage the use `KeyListener` and encourage the use of the Key Bindings API. See [How to use key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Using the default [Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) object from the `java.awt` package, you can use the [drawImage method with 10 parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)):

```
int destinationWidth = ...;
int destinationHeight = ...;
g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, destinationWidth, destinationHeight, 0, 0, originalImage.getWidth(null), originalImage.getHeight(null), null);
```

That way your image will be scaled and painted to `g`. Note that simply by using as in the example provided will stretch and deform your image if the aspect ratio of your window is different from the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: One step scaling scaling isn't the best choice of scaling images

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you elaborate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752 as an example...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I thought it wasn't the best choice because of memory leaks or something like that... But it's only about old dilemma of quality vs. performance. The OP should be aware of that, of course, but it doesn't invalidate de answer.

Comment: Didn't say it was a bad answer, just that it had issues ;)